# Side scrolling on mobile device

Tags: html, mobile, scroll, viewport

I am building a website and am having trouble viewing it on a mobile. The page seams to be able to scroll left and right and I can't figure out why. Using Dev Tools on Chrome and hovering all the elements doesn't show and of them to be widening the page. I am using the code below for my viewport.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
```

I can't post the entire source of the page because I am limited on characters, but I have also ran the source code through w3 validator and can't find the issue on there either.

Emulating the site only shows this error when viewing as a mobile device. Tablet sizes and above are fine.

Any help tracking this error down would be appreciated. Please let me know if you'd like me to post more code up.

Thanks

### EDIT

I'm pretty sure the error is coming from this code inside the navbar.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li>
                    <a class="navbar-timer" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Based on next day delivery using Royal Mail">
                        <span style='color: #959595;'>Want it <span id="orderTimer_Day"></span> <span id="orderTimer_Date"></span>? Order within the next <span id="orderTimer_Hours"></span> hours <span id="orderTimer_Minutes"></span> minutes*</span></a>
                    </li>
                  <li id="link-account"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal_Login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Login</a></li>
                  <li id="link-cart"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal_Basket"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Basket</a></li>
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

`<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=0, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1,width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi" />`

Comment: Use Bootstrap .container-fluid for a full width container, spanning the entire width of your viewport.

Comment: `<div class="container-fluid">`
`your contents here`
`</div>`

Comment: Create your whole webpage in this fluid it will not allow contents to overflow horizontally

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I tried the <meta> tag above and it didn't help. I have tried wrapping the site in the "container-fluid" div and it works but only when the top-nav is situated inside it - which creates an ugly padding around it. Starting the container-fluid div after the top-nav still has the error

Comment: If i remove the left navbar items it solves the issue. I've posted the code I removed above. This must be where the error is.

Comment: just change the `<ul class ="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">` with `<ul class="nav nav-stacked">`  It will remove the horizontal scrollbar